# How to search product.product model with date as condition in Odoo 11

Tags: python-3.x, odoo-11

I'd like to get a product list in Odoo 11 with several conditions by the `search()` method provided in the `product.product` model.

This will get a list (which contains one product with code `12345` if exist)

```
product_object = self.env['product.product']
product = product_object.search([('default_code', '=', '12345')])
```

But I want to filter the list to get products only if its update date is in the past compared to a given date. (NB: `updated_at` is one of my custom fields of `product.product` model, in type `str`

This won't work as expected:

```
product_object = self.env['product.product']
product = product_object.search(
            ['&', ('default_code', '=', '12345'), ('updated_at', '<', '2017-01-10 12:01:00')])
```

The `product` variable always has nothing inside.

How can I search the product.product model with date as condition. Must I change my field type from `string` to `datetime`?

Comment: Please read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and update the subject of your question.

Comment: @buhtz: Do you mean that I need to add Odoo11 in the subject?

Comment: Read the link. Specify the language in the subject.

Comment: Just thought that tags are supposed to be there for that purpose. Thanks.

Comment: Correct. But the subject, too. There are examples for good and bad subjects in the help section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
     **@odoo v11 : Search method with Datetime field.**
```

- Change your updated_at field type as Datetime

  ```
   updated_at = fields.Datetime('Updated Date', required=True)

   current_time = fields.Datetime.now()
   product_object = self.env['product.product']
   product = product_object.search([('default_code', '=', '12345'), ('updated_at', '<', current_time)])
  ```

Comment: and don't forget that the second parameter has to be a datetime object or a compatible object type ,too. '2017-01-10 12:01:00' wouldn't work since it is a string whereas fields.Datetime.now() works since it gives a datetime object